# Error on the Bin of a Normalised Histogram

Tags: statistics, graphing-functions, error-propagation

Suppose I have a histogram, $N$, each with bins of width $\Delta x$, denoted by bin indices, $i$.
The count of a single bin is then $N_{i}$.

I wish to estimate the empirical density for a certain bin. Defining $N_{Total} = \sum^{dim(N)}_{i=0} N_{i}$ and $\hat{N}_{i}$ as the empirical density of a single bin, I can use:

$\hat{N_{i}} = \frac{N_{i}}{N_{total}\Delta x}$

This is a standard method for measuring empirical density. For instance, see [here](https://ocw.tudelft.nl/course-readings/pre-1-3-histogram-probability-density-function/).

Suppose I then wish to calculate the error. By chain rule and the assumption of the Poisson distribution for points in the bin, such that $dN_{i} = \sqrt{N_{i}}$ and  $dN_{Total} = \sqrt{N_{Total}}$.

My solution for the error, using chain rule and solving, is:

$d \hat{N_{i}} = \hat{N_{i}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{N_{i}} + \frac{1}{N_{Total}}}$.

This solution, however, did not include the error on $\Delta x$, which I am fairly sure has an influence on the value $\hat{N_{i}}$ and thus $d\hat{N_{i}}$.

Is my solution correct as is?

Should the error on $\Delta x$ be included in the calculation as well, if this is even applicable?

If so, should the error on the bin width be $d \Delta x = \frac{\Delta x}{2}$?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What is $N$?  The notations are confusing: $\hat{N}_i$ is a proba density, but $N_i$ is a number of counts?  What is known, all the $N_i$?  To know the error on $N_i$, don't you need a model of the expected distribution?

Comment: Of course not, under the assumption that the points within a given bin are Poisson distributed.

Comment: So your model is that the expected counts in each bin are the observed counts?

Comment: Exactly. This is, as far as I know, a standard assumption when calculating errors on bin counts in a histogram.

Comment: Interesting - I am more used to seeing the errors determined from the fluctuations of the counts expected from the model.

Comment: Sorry, to be clear, I use the root of the count, under the assumption of Poisson distributed points in the bin.

Answer (score 2):

*Some comments on density estimation:* As you pursue
your efforts to approximate a population density by
histograms, here is some background information you may find helpful.

**Density histograms.** In R, you can use the parameter `prob=T` with the
`hist` procedure to get a histogram in which the total area of all bars in the histogram is $1.$ That makes
it feasible to plot on the same axes the density curve of the continuous distribution from which the data were randomly sampled. For reasonably large samples there is usually a good match between the histogram and the density function.

Consider a random sample `x` of size $n = 500$ from
the distribution $\mathsf{Gamma}(\mathrm{shape}=\alpha=6, \mathrm{rate} = \lambda = 0.1),$ which has mean $\mu = \alpha/\lambda = 60.$

```
set.seed(429)
x = rgamma(500, 6, .1)
summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  4.696  40.811  56.335  58.977  74.251 156.755 

hdr = "n = 500: GAMMA(6, .1)"
hist(x, prob=T, ylim=c(0,.02), col="skyblue2", label=T, main=hdr)
 curve(dgamma(x, 6, .1), add=T, col="brown", lwd=2)
```

[image]

The width of each bar is 20 and I have put labels to show the heights (densities) of the bars. [Also. see the Note at the end.]

**Kernel density estimation (KDE).** A kernel density estimator seeks to approximate the population density function by using a mixture of 'kernels' (shapes, which can be chosen to be rectangles, normal density functions, etc.) You may want to read the Wikipedia
article on 'kernel density estimation' and perhaps
some of its references--especially, those by B. Silverman.)

Here is the same histogram as above. The default KDE from R is shown as a dotted curve. Tick marks along the horizontal axis show positions of the 500 observations.

```
hdr2 = "n = 500: KDE (dotted) and GAMMA(6, .1) PDF"
hist(x, prob=T, ylim=c(0,.02), col="skyblue2", main=hdr2); rug(x)
 curve(dgamma(x, 6, .1), add=T, col="brown")
 lines(density(x), lty="dotted", lwd=2)
```

[image]

The KDE is computed without regard to the histogram; if I had chosen different cutpoints for the histogram bars, the KDE would be the same. [Below, parameter `br=25` was used to 'suggest' using more bars--perhaps too many.]

[image]

**Empirical CDFs (ECDFs).** The empirical CDF of a sample is made by sorting the sample of size $n$ from smallest to largest, starting at $0$ on the left, the ECDF increases by $1/n$ at each observation, reaching $1$ at the right.

Often an ECDFs gives a more accurate
view of the CDF of the population than a histogram gives of the density function (because ECDFs do not rely
on arbitrary binning). Below the ECDF of `x` is compared with the CDF of $\mathsf{Gamma}(6,.1).$

```
plot(ecdf(x), col="skyblue2")
 curve(pgamma(x, 6, .1), add=T, col="brown", lwd=2)
```

[image]

*Note:* In R, a non-plotted histogram is a list
of details of the numbers used to make a histgram, some of which are copied below:

```
 hist(x, prob=T, plot=F)

$breaks
[1]   0  20  40  60  80 100 120 140 160

$counts
[1]  10 109 169 121  62  19   6   4

$density
[1] 0.0010 0.0109 0.0169 0.0121 0.0062 0.0019 0.0006 0.0004

$mids
[1]  10  30  50  70  90 110 130 150
```

Comment: Thank you for this very in-depth and useful reply. Sadly, I already know all of this and use it regularly. My method is a fairly standard way of normalising histograms: please have a look here, in particular under the heading 'Empirical Densities': https://ocw.tudelft.nl/course-readings/pre-1-3-histogram-probability-density-function/